# Drupal Taxonomy menu - getting it working with views

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

I want to create a taxonomy menu of tags which point to view of documents filtered according to the tag id.

Taxonomy menus can do this, but in the documentation it says it requires Taxonomy menu custom path, and taxonomy menu hierarchy modules. But they are nowhere to be found. So in my taxonomy edit page, under taxonomy menu, I don't get the complete options. Under 'menu path type' I only get one option, 'default'

This is in reference to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://drupal.org/node/1035446) addresses the issue and (starting at comment #9) offers a patch and suggestion, though it looks like it's still acting buggy for D7.

Comment: aha! right. I was pretty confused. I've tried the patch, but that doesn't really do anything for me. I guess I'll have to find another solution.